Converting efficientdet-d2 from tensorflow to onnx and getting issues
I am using EfficientDet model and trying to convert it into onnx using the official example given here.
When I am doing this and visualizing the model using netron app, I am seeing the input tensor as this -

This is making the model not able to do inferencing. The command I used to convert is this -
python3 -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model ./tmp/efficientdet-d2-saved_model --output ./tmp/efficientdet-d2.onnx --opset 12

I checked online how to avoid this issue and found that we need to specify the input tensor name and using this script, I got the input and output tensor names.
import tensorflow as tf
gf = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
m_file = open('tmp/efficientdet-d2-saved_model/efficientdet-d2_frozen.pb','rb')
gf.ParseFromString(m_file.read())

with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as the_file:
    for n in gf.node:
        the_file.write(n.name+'\n')

file = open('somefile.txt','r')
data = file.readlines()
print ("\noutput name = ")
print (data[len(data)-1])

print ("Input name = ")
file.seek ( 0 )
print (file.readline())

This above script gave me the output as -
output name =
detections
Input name =
image_files

So after this I used the --input with tf2onnx like this -
python3 -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model ./tmp/efficientdet-d2-saved_model --output ./tmp/efficientdet-d2.onnx --opset 13 --inputs "image_files:[1,3,768,768]"

My  input shape is 1,3,768,768. But using the above command, I am keep getting this error -
ValueError: Failed to import metagraph, check error log for more info.

How do we convert this correctly so that I can get input tensor as 1,3,768,768 instead of unk_3256, etc.
Thanks
ABD

The unk_ values indicate that the dimension are dynamic, i.e can be set by to an arbitrary value by the inference session. It should not prevent inference. You have another issue somewhere else. Have you check the error log like the error suggested you to?
